# It takes up to 10-20sec to wake up from suspend, and high fan speed when plugged to AC, Why?

Tags: greeter, suspend, lenovo

have a Lenovo Ideapad 310, Intel i7 7th gen, 8GB DDR4 RAM and HDD instead of SSD. Boot time is acceptable, but when I open the lid to wake up the laptop from suspend, elementary takes 10 to 20 seconds to show login screen (and in Windows 10 wake up works instantaneously).

Any idea of what could be happening?

Also, I've noticed that when the laptop is plugged to AC, fan speed skyrockets despite cpu being cold. What the hell is going on?

I installed preload and tlp.

EDIT: After hours staying in suspend mode, I opened the lid and the laptop woke up instantaneously. Maybe the problem is a too short spread between suspending and waking up.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is interesting! Are you sure the laptop is suspending and not hibernating?

Comment: @Schyken I think I'm sure as the settings are working well (I set "when I close the lid -> suspend")